# SQL 2008 Using Top Avg an top row field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

With the results of `Loc_1` query below, I would like to include the top row balance field 100.

```
select AVG(Age) as AvgAge , Balance as BalanceLeft from
(
select top(5)* from Employee
where LocationID=1
order by HireDate desc
) as Loc_1

Age HireDate LocationID  Balance  
30  10-12-2014 1          100  
20  09-12-2014 1          200  
40  08-12-2014 1          300  
50  07-12-2014 1          400  
20  06-12-2014 1          500
```

*Results*

```
AvgAge Balanceleft  
32      100
```

**i just want to include just the top row column balance i.e 100**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation, if I understand the question correctly:

```
select AVG(Age) as AvgAge,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then Balance end) as BalanceLeft
from (select top(5) e.*,
             row_number() over (order by hiredate desc) as seqnum
      from Employee e
      where LocationID=1
      order by HireDate desc
     ) Loc_1
```

Comment: Thanks this works great! I have 5 locations and need 5 results. i guess its simple to use UNION the rows as one dataset..